# Why are my flashvars 'undefined'?

Tags: flash, actionscript, actionscript-2

I trying to access a flashvar on the first frame but they are alway undefined. What am I doing wrong?

Embed:

```
<embed height="300" width="460" FlashVars="config=test" wmode="window" alt=""
 classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" salign="t" allowscriptaccess="always" 
 quality="Autolow" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" name="InteractiveTool" id="InteractiveTool" 
 style="" src="calc_thr_004.swf" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" />
```

ActionScript:

```
trace("level0: " + _level0.config);
trace("root: " + root.config);
```

The results of this this are:

```
level0: undefined
root: undefined
```

This was developed in AS2. How can I get the value of 'config' from the flashvar?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It's been a while since I've used AS2 or FlashVars, but that looks correct to me.  Some things to double-check:

- Is your `<embed>` tag inside an `<object>` tag which does not have the FlashVars parameter?
- Are you using at least Flash Player version 6?  FlashVars were not supported prior to this version.

Either of these things could cause the contents FlashVars to not be passed to the top level of the movie.

Comment: The embed tag is not within an object tag. Should it be?

Comment: Ok.. so it looks like you need the OBJECT tag for IE compatibly. I added it. Shouldn't I still expect FF to see the vars?

Comment: @Nick You are correct, the object tag (if it existed) would only be there for IE compatibility.  You are also correct that if it weren't there, it won't be causing the problem.  How about the Flash Player version?

Comment: +1 for your effort. I found out the problem was with some 'sanitization' that was happening in an AS class of ours. I voted to close the question as no one here could have anticipated that; obviously. Thanks for you help!